# Having an issue with displaying time left to a school class

Tags: javascript, math, arraylist, difference

I have a problem with this code:

```
    <script>

function timeCounter(){

public var endtime = [29700000, 32400000, 36000000, 38700000, 44100000, 46800000, 53100000];

public var currentTime = new Date(n.getFullYear(), n.getMonth(), n.getDate(), n.getHours(), n.getMinutes(), n.getSeconds(), n.getMilliseconds());

public var miliseconds = 1;

public var seconds = miliseconds * 1000;

public var minutes = seconds * 60;

public var hours = minutes * 60;

public var days = hours * 24;

public var years = days * 365;



public var numYears = Math.floor(diff / years);

public var numDays = Math.floor((diff % years) / days);

public var numHours = Math.floor((diff % days) / hours);

public var numMinutes = Math.floor((diff % hours) / minutes);

public var numSeconds = Math.round((diff % minutes) / seconds);



 }

  </script>
```

and I want to invoke it in a table like this:

```
 <tr>
    <td> 08:15-09:00 </td>

    <td> 

    <script>

    document.getElementById("t01").innerHTML = numYears;

    setInterval(countDown(endtime), 1000);

    var diff = (document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = endtime[0]); - currentTime;

         document.write("Time left to next class: " (diff / 3600000); " hours and " (diff / 60000); " minutes.");

    </script>

    </td>

  </tr>
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: **What** problem are you having? If you open the browser's error console, do you see error messages there?

Comment: Your examples make little sense. What is `n`? what is `diff`? where is the element `t01`? where and when is method `timeCounter()` executed? Also, is this homework?

Comment: There is no *public* keyword in javascript. It is a future reserved word though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the variables you have defined in your function are accessible outside of that function. Define them outside the function and then set them like so:

```
var globalVariable;

function setVariable(){
  globalVariable = "value";  
}
```

It might also be useful to post the error you're receiving, if any. Maybe the function is never called.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have:

```
<script>
  function timeCounter(){
    public var endtime = [29700000, 32400000, 36000000, 38700000, 44100000, 46800000, 53100000];
```

*public* is a future reserved word. In the above, it's a syntax error. Perhaps you meant:

```
    var endtime = [29700000, 32400000, 36000000, 38700000, 44100000, 46800000, 53100000];
```

which creates a variable within the *timeCounter* function and assigns it an array when the function is called, not before.

Later you have:

```
  document.getElementById("t01").innerHTML = numYears;
```

There is no element with an ID of "t01" in the supplied markup.

*numYears* is created within *timeCounter* and is local to that function. Here it will throw a reference error since it hasn't been defined in the scope of this code.

Then you have:

```
  setInterval(countDown(endtime), 1000);
```

which calls the function *countDown*, passing it the value of *endtime*, which has the same issue as *numYears*. The result is passed to *setInterval*, which is expecting either a function object or some code that can be executed.

You haven't shown the code for *countDown* or indicated what it returns, so it's impossible to say what the result of this will be.

There are many errors in the code. Look at the console, fix them. Fixing the above is a start.

Comment: Well, what I wanted was something to show how much time there is left when you start 8 am at school, as kind of a time schedule add-on.

Comment: There is a [*search*](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+countdown+clock) function at the top of every page, try it (e.g. [*\[javascript\] countdown clock*](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+countdown+clock). ;-)